# Stateless widget is strangely rebuilt

Tags: flutter

### Description

I have a stateful widget `W`. As a state, it has a list `l = [S(), S()]`, where `S` is a stateless widget.

When I swap the elements of `l` inside `setState()` two `S` are rebuilt. In other words, the existing `S` are not reused.

Why?

### Concrete Example

[DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=76bb282e5af3c2ed2abb3ac260319e93)

```dart
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme:
          ThemeData(brightness: Brightness.dark, primaryColor: Colors.blueGrey),
      home: W(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class W extends StatefulWidget {
  const W({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<W> createState() => _WState();
}

class _WState extends State<W> {
  List<Tile> l = [Tile(text: "hello"), Tile(text: "world")];
  // List<ColorCard> l = [ColorCard(), ColorCard()];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () =>
                setState(() => {this.l.insert(1, this.l.removeAt(0))}),
            child: Icon(Icons.swap_horiz)),
        body: Center(
            child: Row(
          children: this.l,
        )));
  }
}

class Tile extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;

  const Tile({required String this.text, super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(children: [
      ColorCard(),
      Text(this.text),
    ]);
  }
}

Color createRandomColor() {
  final colors = [
    Colors.red,
    Colors.blue,
    Colors.yellow,
    Colors.green,
    Colors.purple,
  ];
  return colors[Random().nextInt(colors.length)];
}

class ColorCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final color = createRandomColor();

  ColorCard({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      color: this.color,
    );
  }
}
```

The stateful widget `W` has the state

```dart
List<Tile> l = [Tile(text: "hello"), Tile(text: "world")];
```

and swapping the elements of `l` makes `Tile()` always rebuilt for some reason though `Tile` extends `StatelessWidget`.

[image]

`Tile` has this structure:

```
Tile (stateless)
- Stack
  - ColorCard (stateless)
    - Container
  - Text
```

More strangely, when I comment the first line and uncomment the second line in the snippet below, then `ColorCard()` is **not** rebuilt at all ([DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=8bd9998b84ade373daedea7a448e43dc)).

```dart
  List<Tile> l = [Tile(text: "hello"), Tile(text: "world")];
  // List<ColorCard> l = [ColorCard(), ColorCard()];
```

[image]

Adding a key to `Tile()` solves the problem ([DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=53c4ad505b9271d8d75058653b75dc3c)),

```dart
  List<Tile> l = [
    Tile(key: UniqueKey(), text: "hello"),
    Tile(key: UniqueKey(), text: "world")
  ];
  // List<ColorCard> l = [ColorCard(), ColorCard()];
```

though I thought keys aren't required as [*Keys! What are they good for?*](https://medium.com/flutter/keys-what-are-they-good-for-13cb51742e7d) says

> *If you find yourself adding, removing, or reordering a collection of widgets of the same type that **hold some state**, using keys is likely in your future.*

[image]

Why?

Comment: Excellent question. While I don't know for sure, I believe it has to do with the fact that in a way a `StatelessWidget` only is truly stateless when it has a `const` constructor and all widgets in the build method are also `const`. I believe "hold some state" is used in a more loose definition and doesn't necessarily only refer to `StatefulWidgets`. But I'm also a bit guessing and it doesn't really explain why it does work correctly when using the `ColorCards` directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every `StatelessWidget` within widget `W` will be rebuilt when you rebuild `W` with calling `setState`, this is what Flutter does. Stateless widgets are not constants, being stateless means only that they are immutable after they are created and inserted into the widget tree and do not have an internal, changeable state that should be reflected in the UI of that particular widget.

Since calling `ColorCard()` is within the `build` method of `Tile`,

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(children: [
      ColorCard(),
      Text(this.text),
    ]);
  }
```

every time the `build` method is called (and it will be called by using `setState` in `_WState`), the constructor of `ColorCard` widget will be executed and will result in a random color. That's why you experience colors changing in the first version.

On the other hand side, in the second version, when you uncomment,

```
List<ColorCard> l = [ColorCard(), ColorCard()];
```

something different happens. The random colors are assigned to both `ColorCard` widgets once they are created as elements in the `l` list, once their constructors run. With `setState` you change the order of the two elements but they are not re-created so the constructors don't run again, meaning the colors will not change.

You can easily test this behaviour in the second version if you change the code so that the color is not assigned to `ColorCard` in the constructor but in the `build` method. Define `ColorCard` like this,

```
class ColorCard extends StatelessWidget {

  ColorCard({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      color: createRandomColor(),
    );
  }
}
```

and you will have the colors changing in the second version as well, since the function `createRandomColor()` is now called from the `build` method.

Comment: I recommend future readers should also see [@SrPanda's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76223360/8776746) especially for the existence of [`Widget::canUpdate()`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/84a1e904f4/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart#L380) function.

Answer (score 2):

The strange part comes from the [canUpdate](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/84a1e904f4/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart#L380) check that widgets have, without a key, every element in an array of the same type is equal and that translates to *everything can be updated, A(key: null) is equal to A(key: null)*, then because stateless components [always rebuild](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/84a1e904f4/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart#L5162) every parent `setState` will require a new `build` from every non instantiated child.

Doesn't that mean that it can't hold a "state"?, well, there are other checks ([like this one](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/84a1e904f4/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart#L3664)) to verify that there is a need to rebuild something; in the drag example you can see that `SquareCard.build` is being called and nothing changes.

With that in [this pad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=76bb282e5af3c2ed2abb3ac260319e93) the fix is quite simple, the actual effect is that tells flutter that the widgets are not same and swaps them.

```
-  const Tile({required String this.text, super.key});
+  Tile({required String this.text}) : super(key: ValueKey(text));
```

A great example for this would be draggable objects, here there are two *"kinds"* of the same `SquareCard`, the instantiated wont get changed except when 2 of them swap places bought get rebuilt with the same color and the tree component (the one with *'Add / Remove'*) will always get rebuilt on every state (using a key wont change anything for this one).

(With *'Add / Remove'*, to add, drag it to an element on the wrap; to remove, drag the element to it)

```
class DragPage extends StatefulWidget {
  DragPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<DragPage> createState() => _DragPage();
}

// Maps the dragged to the target
typedef SrcDst = MapEntry<SquareCard, SquareCard>;

class _DragPage extends State<DragPage> {
  late final cards = List<Widget>.generate(
    5, (i) => SquareCard(text: 'Card $i', stream: _drag_stream)
  );

  final _drag_stream = StreamController<SrcDst>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    _drag_stream.stream.listen(
      (SrcDst ev) {
        print('${ev.key} > ${ev.value}');

        var widget_ph;
        var src_index = cards.indexOf(ev.key);
        var dst_index = cards.indexOf(ev.value);

        if (src_index == -1) {
          widget_ph = SquareCard(
            text: 'Card ${cards.length}',
            stream: _drag_stream,
          );
        } else {
          widget_ph = cards.removeAt(
            cards.indexOf(ev.key),
          );
        }
        if (dst_index != -1) {
          cards.insert(dst_index, widget_ph);
        }
        setState(() => null);
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          SizedBox(
              width: 350,
              child: Wrap(
                children: cards,
              )),
          Center(
            child: SquareCard(
              text: 'Add / Remove',
              stream: _drag_stream,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

A small thing to point here is that `toStringShort()` prints out the key used if there was one, so if you add one, on the build it will show witch one was.

```
class SquareCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  final StreamController<SrcDst> stream;
  final Color color = Color(0xFF000000 | Random().nextInt(0xFFFFFF));

  SquareCard({super.key, required this.text, required this.stream});

  Widget build_card(BuildContext ctx, bool is_drag) {
    return Container(
      color: is_drag ? color.withAlpha(180) : color,
      child: Center(child: Text(text)),
      height: 100,
      width: 100,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext ctx) {
    print('Building ${this.toStringShort()}');
    return DragTarget<SquareCard>(
      builder: (ctx, a, r) {
        return Draggable<SquareCard>(
          feedback: Material(child: build_card(ctx, true)),
          childWhenDragging: build_card(ctx, true),
          child: build_card(ctx, false),
          data: this,
        );
      },
      onAccept: (SquareCard other) => stream.add(
        SrcDst(other, this),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And the rest of the code.

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const App());

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext ctx) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: DragPage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```